# How to input negative numbers into a list

Tags: python, whitespace, negative-number

I require some help since whenever I input a negative number the list it interprets it as a separate element so once it gets to sorting it puts all the negative symbols at the beginning. The end goal of the code is to sort 2 merged lists without using the default sort functions. Also if there is a better way to get rid of spaces in a list I would appreciate it, since at the moment I have to convert the list to a string and replace/strip the extra elements that the spaces cause.

```
list1 = list(input())
list2 = list(input())
mergelist = list1 + list2

print(mergelist)


def bubble_sort(X):
    nums = list(X)
    for i in range(len(X)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(X)):
            if X[j] < X[i]:
                X[j], X[i] = X[i], X[j]
    return X

mergelist = bubble_sort(mergelist)
strmergelist = str(mergelist)

strmergelist = strmergelist.replace("'", '')
strmergelist = strmergelist.replace(",", '')
strmergelist = strmergelist.strip('[]')
strmergelist = strmergelist.strip()

print(strmergelist)
```

The output for lists with no negatives is:

```
1 2 3 4 4 5 5
```

However with negatives it becomes:

```
- - - - 1 2 3 3 4 4 5
```

and my first print function to just check the merging of the lists looks like this when I input any negatives (ignore the spaces since I attempt to remove them later):

```
['1', ' ', '-', '2', ' ', '3', '3', ' ', '-', '4', ' ', '-', '4', ' ', '-', '5']
```

Comment: What format are you supposed to be entering `list1` and `list2` in... for instance... If you're entering `-1 2 -3`... you probably want to be splitting on spaces and then converting each word into an integer before sorting... That way you're not having to strip things/remove brackets etc... You want to be working with lists of *numbers* - not individual characters...

Comment: so I'm guessing `list1 = [int(n) for n in input().split()]` and the same for `list2` is probably going to sort you out here...

Comment: Those are string. Wouldn't a negative number list be  [-1,-2] ?

Comment: He's getting the numbers from an Input, but I cannot see that he translates the input into Integers, therefore even if the splitting of the variables were correct, `"-1" < "-2"` would the `True`, because it's looking at the ASCII-value of the characters.

Comment: Why are you calling `str` on a list? Just do `" ".join(mergelist)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list()` doesn't parse a string to a list of integers, it turns an iterable of items into a list of items.
To read a list from the console, try something like:

```
def read_list():
    """
    read a list of integers from stdin
    """
    return list(map(int, input().split()))

list1 = read_list()
list2 = read_list()
```

`input.split()` reads one line of user input and will separate it by whitespace - basically to words.

`int()` can convert a string to an integer.

`map(int, ...)` returns an iterable which applies `int()` to each "word" of the user input.

The final call to `list()` will turn the iterable to a list.

This should handle negative numbers as well.

Additionally, I see that you want to print the resulting list without extra character. I recommend this:

```
print(' '.join(mergelist))
```